# Query parameteriztion in SoapUI JDBC Requests

Tags: jdbc, soapui, parameterization

My test has 2 JDBC Requests.
I'd like to use the results of the first JDBC Request in the WHERE clause of the second JDBC request.

For example, querying a DB2 database, I have tried:

1. JDBC Request 1: `select member_id from Employees fetch first 1 row only`
2. JDBC Request 2: `select bonus_amount from EmployeesBonuses where member_id = '${JDBC Request 1#ResponseAsXml#//MEMBER_ID}'`

Unfortunately, this method of referencing doesn't work.
Further, the 2 steps above reference different databases, so constructing a join'd statement is not possible.

Comment: corrected the syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because *Property Expansion* does not work in sql query of Jdbc Request step.

Instead, have the query for 2nd as given below:

```
select bonus_amount from EmployeesBonuses where member_id = :MEMBERID
```

Above to the sql query, SoapUI allows to define the parameters. Define a parameter, `MEMBERID` and provide the value as *Property Expansion* i.e., `${#JDBC Request 1#ResponseAsXml#//MEMBER_ID}`.

Now, try executing the query. For more details of query parameterization in SoapUI, refer [documentation](https://www.soapui.org/jdbc/reference/the-jdbc-request-window.html)

Comment: This worked. Except that there is a small typo (originally in my question, itself). It should be '${JDBC Request 1#ResponseAsXml#//MEMBER_ID} - no # required before the step name. Thanks!